# Get the value that is not matched with matching element from array with two elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of two elements

```
var a = ['a','b'];
```

I have remover variable as `var remover = 'a'`

i want the result variable as `var result = 'b'`

i tried it as

```
var current_id = 'windows123456';
var allIds = People.Ids();  // this will have ['windows123456','windows123']
var index = allIds.indexOf(current_id);
  if (index >= 0) {
      allIds.splice( index, 1 );
  }
console.log(allIds[0]); //windows123
```

Any Easy way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do this for two-element arrays, this will work:

```
var result = a.find(item => item != remover);
```

If you need to work with longer arrays, this returns `['b']`:

```
var result = a.filter(item => item != remover);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may destructure the array:

```
var [remover,result]=a;
```